# Snippets sorting in SOLR is not working correctly

Tags: solr

In SOLR, I am performing query on text field like below:

```
Contents:(through project)
```

Fragment size is set to value such that I am getting more than 1 snippet. 
Issue is that, snippets order I got from SOLR is not correct.

I think, snippet order is based on relevance. Is there a way to get snippets in same order as of documents(without any sorting/default sorting)?

Example document:

> This site is a catalog of Apache Software Foundation **project**. It is
>   designed to help you find specific projects that meet your interests
>   and to gain a broader understanding of the wide variety of work
>   currently underway in the Apache community.
>
> All projects data is maintained by the individual projects themselves.
>   If you do not find the projects you are looking for here, you can
>   browse **through** the top-level **Project** Management Committees starting at
>   the Apache Software Foundation homepage. Then be sure to encourage the
>   project to submit their information here.

SOLR result snippets:

> 1. ... can browse **through** the top-level **Project** Management Committees ...
> 2. ... site is a catalog of Apache Software Foundation **project**. It is ...

Second snippet should come first according to content in document.

Comment: Highlighting snippets should included in the same sequence as your documents - otherwise it'd be impossible to know which document has which highlighted section. Remember that `is` and `the` are both usually extracted as stopwords and removed from the index.

Comment: "otherwise it'd be impossible to know which document has which highlighted section" - Yes off course. Snippets are returned against primary key. Problem is, I am getting multiple snippets of a document which are not sorted.

Comment: Please add an example, it's hard to say anything in particular without an example of your issue.

Comment: Example has been added. Kindly let me know if anything is still unclear.